# In-app messaging Landing page action in Urban Airship

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I integrated Urban Airship in my app for push notifications and In-App messaging. By using the **landing page** action i can able to send the push message in foreground or background state and as mentioned by them, the message is showing when the user is opening the app for the next time.

But i want to show the In-App notification with landing page action when the app received it in foreground state and immediately

In the docs of Urban Airship they mentioned

> If you need to display a Landing Page while the app is in the foreground state, replace the registry predicate associated with that action with one that allows foreground execution.

please find the url

http://docs.urbanairship.com/user-guide/message-composer.html#in-app-message

can someone please tell me what is the "registry predicate" that they mentioned and how to achieve my requirement

Comment: face same problem.. any solution?

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh no i didn't find any solution.. i even posted it in urban airship community, but no solution till now

Comment: how did you resolved this problem

Comment: I just kept this on hold..

Comment: Tell me first, if you get any solution.

Comment: @SankalapYadurajSingh sure